# How to get underlying CSS value using plain old javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get hold of the actual CSS value defined in the CSS rather than a computed evaluation of the value using plain old javascript.

i.e. I have a display:grid that has a grid-template-columns set to "200px 1fr", and I want to see this exact string in javascript; the problem I get is that if I use *mygrid.style.gridTemplateColumns* then I get nothing, and if I use *getComputedStyle* then I get the "1fr" part evaluated into a runtime amount (and not with the "1fr" part that I need).

(The reason I need this is because the CSS also has media variants that change this depending on the screensize)

I have the following sample trying to visualize the problem:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
#mygrid {
width: 100%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 100px auto;
grid-template-areas: 
 "mytop mytop 
  myleft myright";
background-color: yellow;
align-content: start;
}  
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="mygrid" style='width:100%'></div>

<script>
var mygrid=document.getElementById('mygrid');
console.log('gtc:['+mygrid.style.gridTemplateColumns+'] cs='+getStyle(mygrid,'grid-template-columns'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Running this will get a console log result seeing

```
gtc: cs=200px ####px
```

but I want to see

```
gtc:  cs=200px 1fr"
```

To see this fully, please see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/s086ovc7/ (or with the media entries: https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/s086ovc7/29/)

Running this jsfiddle gives you the following output (note actual values will vary depending on your window size):

```
DIV
width:[100%] cs=####px
height:[] cs=###px
gtc:[] cs=200px ####px
```

I want to see

```
DIV
.
.
gtc:[] cs=200px 1fr     <---------- "1fr"
```

Is there a way to do get this ("200px 1fr")?

Thanks
Abe

PS. Don't know why the grid html output isn't behaving but I'm not fussed by that for the moment.

Comment: There is no trivial way to do that.

Comment: If it's specified in a `style` tag you can get the textContent and run a regex match against it. Good luck with that.

Comment: `[...document.styleSheets].forEach(x => [...x.cssRules].forEach(y => console.log(y.cssText)))` *should* work but only if the css and the js are served from the same domain: otherwise you'll get a DOMException in chrome and a SecurityError in Firefox.

Comment: Here's an implementation of that: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/devf7ozb/

Comment: Thanks Jared/Chris, that does work, but alas I have media entries that vary this that don't show up. :-(

    *@media screen and (max-width:650px) {
       #mygrid {
       grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr;
       }
    }*

Comment: Fixed the fiddle accordingly

Comment: This is great code, far above my capability, but is there a way to see just the currently active CSS property?

Comment: Here's an improved version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nk28do19/ (not exactly more readable though ;) CSS rule priority is complex, there's no way to find out which one applies without essentially writing your own CSS engine. A later rule for instance does not always override a previous one if the previous one is more specific. In this special case you could of course compare the CSSMediaRule's selector (which contains the screen width constraint) and compare it against the current width.

Comment: You might need to consider to revise your approach completely. Can't you somehow use the measured dimensions of the table cells to get to the CSS value?

Comment: Here's a version that filters out media rules that don't fit the current width: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nk28do19/2/ the `200px 1fr` value has no media rule though so will always be part of the resulting array.

Comment: Thanks everyone; I'm not seeing these filters work, and the code is all black magic to me, but as ChrisG suggests - I think I'm going to need to rethink my approach and apply some assumption based logic instead. Thanks for your help though.